# When to nest mark property in Layer versus Top-Level Vega-lite spec?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am wondering how Vega-lite works with respect to tying Marks to associated Encodings.

In the below example, both the encoding and the mark are at the "top-level" of the spec:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

And with the simplest layer example, both the bar mark and the text mark are nested in the Layer  property

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Bar chart with text labels. Apply scale padding to make the frame cover the labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"padding": 10}}
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": "bar"
  }, {
    "mark": {
      "type": "text",
      "align": "left",
      "baseline": "middle",
      "dx": 3
    },
    "encoding": {
      "text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
    }
  }]
}
```

- In this case, am I correct to assume that any Mark in the Layer property automatically inherits the encodings at the top-level?
- Further, I notice that I cannot move the bar Mark outside of the Layer property (Vega Editor prompts that this is not an allowed property and bars fail to render if placed in top-level).
- Finally, in more complicated example still (see: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/layer_line_mean_point_raw.html), the encodings are repeated in the layer (despite having a redundant x encoding) -> so in this case, when is it appropriate to place encoding at the top level versus in the layer?

The Vega-lite docs go into a fair bit of detail about the configuration of these properties but I have not been able to find a conceptual answer to these 3 questions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vega-Lite provides a hierarchical chart model, where each level in the hierarchy can override various properties declared in the parent level. In terms of layer specifications, the relevant concepts are this:

- a `UnitSpec` is what you think of as a single chart: it it, you can specify `data`, `mark`, `encodings`, `transforms`, and other properties.
- a `LayerSpec`, is a container that can hold a number of `UnitSpec` or `LayerSpec` specifications in the `layers` property. Additionally, you can specify `data`, `encodings` `transforms`, and other properties (but not `mark`).

A `UnitSpec` that is within a `LayerSpec` or other top-level object will inherit any properties specified there (such as `data`, `encodings`, `transforms`, etc.), and is also able to override them by specifying its own `data`, `encodings`, or `transforms`.

Similar hierarchical concepts apply to other compound chart types, such as `ConcatSpec`, `VConcatSpec`, `HConcatSpec`, `FacetSpec`, etc.

More concretely, in your example, the `data` and some `encodings` are defined in the top-level layer:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Bar chart with text labels. Apply scale padding to make the frame cover the labels.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"padding": 10}}
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": "bar"
  }, {
    "mark": {
      "type": "text",
      "align": "left",
      "baseline": "middle",
      "dx": 3
    },
    "encoding": {
      "text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
    }
  }]
}
```

In terms of the inheritance from parent, this is functionally equivalent to the following, where I have moved `data` and `encodings` from the top-level into each contained `UnitSpec`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Bar chart with text labels. Apply scale padding to make the frame cover the labels.",
  "layer": [{
    "data": {
      "values": [
        {"a": "A", "b": 28},
        {"a": "B", "b": 55},
        {"a": "C", "b": 43}
      ]
    },
    "mark": "bar"
    "encoding": {
      "y": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
      "x": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"padding": 10}}
    },
  }, {
    "data": {
      "values": [
        {"a": "A", "b": 28},
        {"a": "B", "b": 55},
        {"a": "C", "b": 43}
      ]
    },
    "mark": {
      "type": "text",
      "align": "left",
      "baseline": "middle",
      "dx": 3
    },
    "encoding": {
      "y": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
      "x": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"padding": 10}}
      "text": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
    }
  }]
}
```

Specifying shared properties at the top level is a way to make chart specifications more concise and understandable.